# jQuery mobile: clientX and clientY and the taphold event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using the taphold event in my project and need the coordinates of the point where the user tapped. Unfortunately, event.clientX and event.clientY are undefined (cp. my example [here](http://cip.uni-trier.de/~baltes/Client/)).
Is there a possibility to get these coordinates similar to the onclick-event?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to cheat a bit, I made a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/STLWn/

```
$(document).on('vmousedown', function(event){
    holdCords.holdX = event.pageX;
    holdCords.holdY = event.pageY;
});

$(document).on('taphold', function(e){
    alert('X: ' + holdCords.holdX + ' Y: ' + holdCords.holdY ); 
});

var holdCords = {
    holdX : 0,
    holdY : 0
}
```

Tested on desktop Firefox, Android 4.1.1 Chrome and iPad 6.0